# Validity or Invalidity

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How to prove validity of this since the conclusion does not seem to have any link with the premises?

> Murder is always wrong
>
> Sometimes murder is not wrong
>
> Therefore, the death penalty should be illegal

Comment: The first two assertions are contradictory, so it is impossible to find a counterexample where the first two assertions are both true but the third is false, thus demonstrating the validity of the argument.  This is the principle of explosion, and does not mean the the third assertion is true (or false) in itself, just that it is implied by the combination of the first two assertions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To say an argument is valid is not to say the conclusion is true but to say the premises imply the conclusion.

So If you premises are $A=$ Murder is always wrong and $B = $ Murder is sometimes not wrong, and your conclusion is $C=$ Snails eat ping-pong balls.  Then the argument is valid if $A \land B \implies C$ is true.

As $B = \lnot A$ and $A\land \lnot A$ is always false (no matter what $A$ is).  And for any false statement $D$ then $D \implies C$ is always true (no matter what $C$ is).

So $(A \land \lnot A) \implies C$ is always true and

1) $A$ 2) $\lnot A$ Conc: $C$ is always valid.  (But pretty dang useless.)